# Excel VBA puts extra blank line at end of text file when exporting

Tags: vba, text, excel

I have an Excel VBA macro that outputs to a text file. There is always a blank row at the bottom of the text file and I am having trouble getting rid of it. Any useful suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

```
Sub testExport()

  Dim fPath As String, exportTxt As String
  fPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\Sample_" & Format(Now(), "HHNNSS") & ".txt"

  exportTxt = "Project: Sample Output" & vbCrLf
  exportTxt = exportTxt & "Model Version: 1 "


  Open fPath For Append As #1    'write the new file
  Print #1, exportTxt
  Close #1
```

End Sub

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the help on the `Print #` statement and ways to specify `charpos` after the data has been output:

> *charpos* Specifies the insertion point for the next character. Use a
>   semicolon to position the insertion
>   point immediately after the last
>   character displayed. Use Tab(n) to
>   position the insertion point to an
>   absolute column number. Use Tab with
>   no argument to position the insertion
>   point at the beginning of the next
>   print zone. If charpos is omitted, the
>   next character is printed on the next
>   line.

Try the following instead:

```
Print #1, exportTxt;
```

Comment: what if I want to do it only for the last blank line?

Answer (score 2):

What I did and worked was, after I created the txt file, 
counted the lines with data I wanted to be copied, and then loop through it creating a new file using the Print #1, exportTxt; and also Print #1, "", except in the last row.

```
Open sOrgFile For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
iCounter = iCounter + 1
Line Input #1, sData
If sData = "" Then Exit Do
Loop
Close #1

Open sOrgFile For Input As #1
Open sDestFile For Output As #2
Do While Not EOF(1)
iCounter2 = iCounter2 + 1
Line Input #1, sData
    If sData = "" Then Exit Do
Print #2, sData;
If iCounter2 <> iCounter Then Print #2, ""
sData = ""
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Print #1, exportTxt;
```

it prints everything in one line. no line break at all.