# select range & copy/paste to notepad - Almost done

Tags: vba, excel

After a lot of work and testing (very pathetic indeed), I finally managed to select a range in *worksheets*, then copy/paste it in Notepad. The file shall be thereafter readen by another app. Unfortunately, the app reject the file and there is no way for me to debug why. The only message I have is an error occuring at *last line*.

Surprisingly, when I copy-paste to notepad by hand, it works. As far as my eyes can see, both txt files (the one writen with my *sub()* and the one from CP by hand) are exactly the same. I guess my eyes are wrong. I suspect there is at the end of last line or below last row maybe some ***white space*** I can not see. The only part of code I do not fully understand is, according to me, the place of the current issue.

Find below part of my code:

```
[code]
' RngSelect is a Variant and effectively a range of cells 
' Txt is a Variant
' LastRow is a Long equal to last row number of my range

With RngSelect
For Lg1 = 1 To LastRow
    Txt = Txt & vbCrLf & Join$(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Rows(Lg1).Value)),vbTab)   ' copy each row    
Next
End With

Open FilePath For Output As #1
Print #1, Mid$(Txt, Len(vbCrLf) + 1)
Close #1

RngSelect = Null
Txt = Null

End Sub
```

If it can help, my file to be imported by the other app can be in a csv format. Currently, my delimiter is **Tab**.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Change `RngSelect = Null` to `Set RngSelect = Nothing` and `Txt = Null` to `Txt = ""` Though at the end of the code, you do not need to set it to anything until and unless `Txt` is not declared in that procedure...

Comment: You may find the functions [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306859/msgbox-not-big-enough-for-text) useful for sending information to Notepad.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Yes, Txt is **not** declared in this procedure. TY for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017968/excel-vba-puts-extra-blank-line-at-end-of-text-file-when-exporting), I finally managed to erase the last blank line at the bottom of my text . The the correct line now is : `Print #1, Mid$(txt, Len(vbCrLf) + 1) ;`

I then had to modify my LastRow, as it is the row number on my spreadsheet but not the last row number on my text file.
I shall now find a way to *append* the text in the text file.